# Routing to multiple Angular 7 projects in Express based on JWT authentication and Role

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt, express-jwt

I have created an Angular 7 project which has multiple applications for different roles, like admin, user, editor, etc. each have different components and view.

A logged in user will land on its user role application, where as any guest user will land on 'website' application which has login and signup page.

My problem is to route using express to different angular applications based on user role determined during authentication. This works with one angular application, but doesn't work with multiple angular application

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (user.isAdmin) {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist/admin/index.html'));
  }
  if (user.isUser) {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist/user/index.html'));
  }
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist/website/index.html'));
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, just had to rename the index.html to different role names such as below,

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (user.isAdmin) {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist/admin/admin.html'));
  }
  if (user.isUser) {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist/user/user.html'));
  }
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist/website/website.html'));
})
```